# Number of "great comment" votes it received?How can I vote others' comment?

Tags: support

I really want to thank some comments to my question.But I just can't find how to do this.Maybe I have not enough reputations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put your pointer on the comment, is there a little up-arrow that appears to the left?  That is where you would up-vote the comment.

Comment: Sorry,I can't see the up-arrow.Maybe I haven't enough reputations?

Comment: Yes!Now I can see it after my reputation rises.Thanks!